# PyDispatch receiving multiple signals when only 1 sent

Tags: python

Alright guys so I have a very simple PyDispatch signals setup going that I am testing, and can't seem to figure out why I am receiving multiple signals every time I send one.

Code:

```
class Strategy():

def __init__(self,name,exchange=Exchange(), system=System()):
    self.SIGNAL='Strategy'
    self.SENDER = 'Strategy'
    self.system = system
    self.name = name
    self.connect_to_system()


def connect_to_system(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.receive_message, signal='System', sender='System')
    self.system.connect_strategy(self.name)

def send_message(self,info, strategy):
    print 'send strat'
    dispatcher.send(signal=self.SIGNAL,sender=self.SENDER,info=info,strategy=strategy)

class System():
    def __init__(self,exchange=Exchange()):
        self.SIGNAL='System'
        self.SENDER='System'
        dispatcher.connect(self.receive_message, signal=dispatcher.Any, sender=dispatcher.Any)

    def receive_message(self, sender, signal, **kwargs):
        if sender == 'Strategy':
            print kwargs, sender, signal
```

This gives me:

```
In [10]: strat.send_message("OK",'sender')
send strat
{'info': 'OK', 'strategy': 'sender'} Strategy Strategy
{'info': 'OK', 'strategy': 'sender'} Strategy Strategy
{'info': 'OK', 'strategy': 'sender'} Strategy Strategy
{'info': 'OK', 'strategy': 'sender'} Strategy Strategy
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

In my code, using:

```
def __init__(self,name,exchange=Exchange(), system=System()):
```

Causes us to call the System(), even when I'm initializing it later myself. I need to just use exchange, system in this instance. I was calling the same **init** in other classes.

On import, it was running 3 times from those calls and then the 4th was the time I actually wanted it to.